# Solve problems with external table

Tags: oracle, load, external

I have problems with some Oracle external table

```
create table myExternalTable
(field1, field2....)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY myDirectory
ACCESS PARAMETERS
(RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
NOLOGFILE
NOBADFILE
NODISCARDFILE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$')
LOCATION ('data.dsv'));
commit;

alter table myExternalTable reject limit unlimited; --solve reject limit reached problem

select * from myExternalTable;
```

When I select on the table I have this error :

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04040: file data.dsv in myDirectory not found
```

It seems that the error description is not right because normally the table is already loaded with data.dsv when created.
Plus data.dsv exists in myDirectory.

What is going on? Can somebody help?

Note :

Instead of the select, this is what I normally do :

```
merge into myDatabaseTable
using
(select field1, field2,.... from myExternalTable) temp
on (temp.field1= myDatabaseTable.field1)
when matched then update
set myDatabaseTable.field1 = temp.field1,
 myDatabaseTable.field2 = temp.field2,
 ......;
```

This works good on my development environment but on some other environment I have the error I said before :

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04040: file data.dsv in myDirectory not found
```

First I thought that, in the environment it does not work, the directory did not point where it had to but selecting on dba_directories table, I could see the path of the directory is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the table is already loaded'? Creating the external table does not attempt to read the file. Are you sure the `myDirectory` Oracle directory object points to where you think it does - on the DB server, not your client, if you're accessing a remote DB - and the file name matches exactly, including the case?

Comment: So you mean the table is loaded when I merge the two tables ?

Comment: file name matches exactly

Comment: Creating the external table object defines it and checks the directory object exists; it doesn't check the underlying O/S directory exists or is valid, and doesn't look at the file Whenever you query the external table it tries to find, open and read the file at that point. If you're in a different environment are you sure the file is in the right directory on the right DB server? We can't see your environment, or how your directory objects are configured, or what servers and directories exist on them...

Comment: I checked that with people in charge of this other environment and everything seems to be where it should be. By the way, if I understand well when I select the table it should load the file in the table

Comment: Yes, but the file doesn't exist where you think it should. (Or possibly isn't readable by the Oracle account, but I think that gets a different error).

Comment: I checked the presence of the file in the folder pointed by the oracle directory (whose path I checked) and it is there... I know, it is like magical but nothing is with computers, right?

Comment: Check the path again, check the file name again, check the permissions.... but also check you're on the right server. That seems the mostly likely explanation at this point - that your environments have DBs which are on different servers, all with the same directory set-up perhaps, and you aren't looking at the right server for this environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with the access rights of the user on the operating system side. It is defined in Oracle Support Note Create Database Directory on Remote Share/Server (Doc ID 739772.1)

For my case, I created the directory with a sysdba and then for allowing other users to accesss that external table, I created another table which is creates by Create Table as Select statement for the external table. Otherwise, I need to map the Windows Oracle Service owner user to the exact Oracle user which is already defined in the note.
So, it is more like a well fitting workaround for my case.

To sum up the steps in a nutshell:

1- Create the external table T2

2- Create a table named T1 with CTAS to external table

3- Give SELECT right to T1

Hope this helps for your case.